# After restoring C drive from a backup, my other drive got wiped?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, backup

This computer started booting very slowly so I decided to restore it from a backup. I used norton ghost 15 like I usually do without any problem.
 There are 2 drives, C:\ and D:\ , and the backup was stored on D:. When I booted to the ghost recovery disk and attempted to restore C from the backup, the computer wasn't able to boot into Windows, despite trying to repair the startup (At this point, D:\ wasn't wiped).
 I tried restoring from the backup again, this time with Master Boot Record checked. It booted seamlessly, but I noticed there was no D:\ drive anymore. I opened the partition manager and I had to create D:\ again, but all the data on it was lost. Luckily, it contained steam games and movies, which I redownloaded later.

The question is, how did this happen? How did C get restored and D got wiped, if the backup was stored on D? I've been backuping/restoring using this program for years, and haven't had any problem.

Notes: The computer didn't have any hardware replaced since the last backup, which I restored to. However, when I installed Windows 7, the installation did not ask for a "system reserved" partition, like it did on other computers. Could that be the cause?
After I noticed that D:\ got wiped, I booted back into ghost, but it couldn't see it either. I restored this computer like 10 times in the past, with 0 problems.

Please don't mark this as "too localised", as it clearly isn't, and anyone might experience this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like you made your image before having a D:/ partition, and so there was no entry for it in your MBR backup. When you restore the MBR data it overwrites your partition table (list of partitions, and sizes) with the old information for the whole drive. Technically your partition wasn't gone, it just wasn't listed anymore, and now operating systems would see it as freely usable space.

You may have been able to use a recovery program to recover it, but that data area is now considered free space so your operating system may start to overwrite it, and make the data unrecoverable. In general recovery programs are a huge waste of time, but if you avoid using the hard drive after such occurs, **sometimes** you can recover files/partitions before they get overwritten.

When doing Windows 7 operating system restores, you only need to restore the MBR if your partitions will be altered (beyond applying a filesystem).

To address you concern about a reserved partitions, no, Windows 7 doesn't need one in general. It won't create one unless you install to unformatted space on a drive where it won't go over the 4 max primary partitions. I do believe a reserved partition is required if you intend to use BitLocker.

Comment: This makes sense until you think if the image was on the partition that was deleted how was the image even applied by an image on a partition that was deleted my guess the image wasn't actually on D